# Aurelia add template to global resources

Tags: templates, aurelia, app-globalresources

I know I can add custom element that has view-model to Aurelia's global resources like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
   aurelia.globalResources("resources/myElement");
   ...
}
```

But how to add html-only template to global resources?
If I include them like in the configuration above, I get errors that my html-only element cannot be found.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found the solution, just need to add .html at the end:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.globalResources("resources/myElement");
    aurelia.globalResources("resources/myHtmlOnlyElement.html");
    ...
}
```